# Interpret outcome of a mixed model meta-regression on reoperation rates

Tags: mixed-model

I am writing a meta-analysis on the comparison of the complication and reoperation rates after 5 different treatment modalities of distal radius fractures. I compared them by using a mixed model meta-regression. What are the estimates and when are the differences significant? We had 4 comparisons on complication rates and 4 comparisons on reoperation rates. Should I use a bonferroni correction of 8(p<0.05/8)?

```
> # Comparison of treatment effects to gold standard in the Reoperations subset
> mtpr2 <- metaprop(Events_n, N, Study_ID, data = Reoperations, comb.random=TRUE)
> meta::metareg(mtpr2, ~Treatment, comb.random=TRUE)

Mixed-Effects Model (k = 34; tau^2 estimator: DL)

tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0.0465 (SE = 0.2637)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0.2155
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 4.63%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   1.05
R^2 (amount of heterogeneity accounted for):            93.48%

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 29) = 30.4076, p-val = 0.3939

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 2:5): 
QM(df = 4) = 24.2367, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

              estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub     
intrcpt        -3.9411  0.4226  -9.3247  <.0001  -4.7695  -3.1127  ***
TreatmentEF     0.9092  0.5375   1.6915  0.0907  -0.1443   1.9627    .
TreatmentIMN    1.3050  0.5354   2.4375  0.0148   0.2557   2.3544    *
TreatmentKW     0.6019  0.6066   0.9922  0.3211  -0.5871   1.7909     
TreatmentVPO    2.3145  0.5207   4.4447  <.0001   1.2939   3.3351  ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Is it correct to say that the odds ratio of EF 2,48233587 (95%CI 0,865628021 to 7,118521149)? Which means EF treatment has a 2,48 higher reoperation rate or a pt treated with an EF is 2,48 more likely to be getting a reoperation than PC.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used the default transformation of proportions you are working on the logit scale. You interpret the coefficients in the same way as you would for a regular regression so the intercept is the value for your reference category and is the log of the odds of being in that category so you need to exponentiate it to get the odds. The other four coefficients are log odds ratios so if you exponentiate them you get an estimate of how much more likely re-operation is than in the reference category. You can similarly transform the upper and lower limits of the confidence interval. You do not have much heterogeneity which is a good thing.

Comment: Thank you. Should I use a bonferroni correction of 8 and therefor a significant difference would have a p<0.05/8?

Comment: I think the best thing is to look at the tag multiple-comparisons on this site and read the top five most voted entries which should give you a much better overview of the issues than I can fit into a comment.

Comment: I have read the articles and looked online. The bonferroni correction is conservative, but I am happy with that. So the differences I will see will have a higher probability of being real true difference. But the question I have is if I should divide my alpha by 4 or by 8. Because I do the same 4 comparisons for complications and reoperations, but with different data from the same studies.